# trouble installing MozRepl

Tags: perl, mozrepl

I've been trying to install WWW::Mechanize::Firefox through CPAN and I am having trouble installing the dependency MozRepl. The installation goes through but the tests all fail, and when I force install it and run my perl script, I run into an error

```
Failed to connect to ,  at /Library/Perl/5.12/MozRepl/RemoteObject.pm line 467.
```

SO I uninstalled MozRepl and looked at the tests I get the following errors in the log:

```
#   Failed test at t/10-plugin-repl-enter.t line 11.
Can't locate object method "repl_enter" via package "MozRepl" at t/10-plugin-repl-enter.t line 12.
```

...

```
#   Failed test at t/20-plugin-json.t line 16.
Can't locate object method "json" via package "MozRepl" at t/20-plugin-json.t line 17.

#   Failed test at t/19-plugin-repl-util-doc_for.t line 14.
Can't locate object method "repl_doc_for" via package "MozRepl" at t/19-plugin-repl-util-doc_for.t line 16.

#   Failed test at t/18-plugin-repl-util-help_url_for.t line 14.
Can't locate object method "repl_help_url" via package "MozRepl" at t/18-plugin-repl-util-help_url_for.t line 16.
```

etc..

I am running on Mac OSX 10.8.4, 4 GB Ram 2.5 Ghz, Perl version 5.12. Does anybody have any idea what is causing these errors?

UPDATE:
i reinstalled mozrepl, and now I get this error when i run my script:

```
Failed to connect to , problem connecting to "localhost", port 4242: Connection refused at /Users/thui/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.16.0/lib/site_perl/5.16.0/MozRepl/Client.pm line 144
```

Comment: Do you use [cpanm](https://metacpan.org/pod/release/MIYAGAWA/App-cpanminus-1.7001/bin/cpanm)? If not it could help you with dependencies versions.

Comment: I'm not sure, but you might need an older version of MozRepl (the firefox addon). I think there have been breaking changes in the API that haven't made it to MozRepl (the perl Package).

Comment: I just installed the MozRepl addon on firefox to no avail. And yes I am using cpanm. I just upgraded my version of Perl to 5.16 to no avail as well.

Comment: I've created an answer with a working recipe below. I installed Debian 7 on a new VM, installed Firefox, installed CPANminus via `cpan`, then followed the recipe.

Comment: Didn't see your update there. If it says `problem connecting to "localhost", port 4242: Connection refused` that means that MozRepl (the Firefox addon) isn't running IN FIREFOX. See the instructions in my answer for how to properly install and configure MozRepl (the Firefox addon).

Answer (score 1):

This works for me with perl 5.10 or later, latest Firefox (26 as of writing) and Mozrepl from github.

At command propmpt:

**(1)** Download MozRepl and build the XPI file (Firefox extension):

```
git clone git://github.com/bard/mozrepl
cd mozrepl
zip -r ../mozrepl.zip *
cd ..
mv mozrepl.zip mozrepl.xpi
```

**(2)** Install the extension in Firefox via about:addons [Install from file].

In Firefox:

**(3)** `Menu`->`Tools`->`Mozrepl`->`Activate On Startup`

**(4)** `Menu`->`Tools`->`Mozrepl`->`Start`

At command propmpt:

**(5)** `which firefox`

Make sure the firefox executable (or your OS's wrapper script) is in `$PATH` - you should get some output!

**(6)** `cpanm WWW::Mechanize::Firefox`

**(7)** Test it!

At this point, if CPANminus reports no errors then WWW::Mechanize::Firefox should be working. The first example from the synopsis is a good test:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use WWW::Mechanize::Firefox;
my $mech = WWW::Mechanize::Firefox->new();
$mech->get('http://google.com');
```

That assumes MozRepl is listening on port 4242 (check in Menu->Tools->Mozrepl->Change Port). You can also change the port from the perl side; see options for `->new()`.

**(8)** `cpanm HTML::Display::Common`

I found that `bcat.pl` from the examples required this module, but it wasn't installed as a dependency.

Comment: hello - i need to re-work your recipe for the OpenSuse version 13.1. I try to install Mecha :: FireFox for a long long time now. All fails.